# ものには… in 「ものには順序というものがある」 Some hidden word or phrase?

Tags: translation, usage

I need some help with translating my Legend of Zelda guidebook.

> ダンジョンアイテムを探せ！Search for dungeon items!
>
> ダンジョンでの目的はもちろんボスを倒すことだが、ものには順序というものがある。
>
> まずはマップとコンパスを手に入れたい。

I'm a bit stuck with the second line. Something like
"In a dungeon the objective is of course beating the boss, but [finding] things there really is an order"

Yeah... a bit stuck as you can see!
I assume ものには is hiding a verb, but even then I am unsure of the sentence.

Typically in the Zelda games you have to find a specific item before you can get to other chambers and then fight the boss. So it must be referring to that.

Comment: 参考までに　http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E7%89%A9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF%E9%A0%86%E5%BA%8F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B

Comment: Another example is 「ものには限度がある」 (there are always limits to everything), which is often used by someone who is about to lose his patience.

Comment: One of my dictionaries paraphrases it 「どんなものにも正しい順序がある」 *There is a proper order for everything*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "ものには" means "Things".

"All things have order." or "All things are set in the sequence."

In this case, translation might be

> Of course, the target task in the dungeon is defeating the Boss but you should do something before do it.

And I'd like you to post the next phrase, I guess there is a clue in it.

Comment: I've added the next line. It says first of all you will want to get the map and compass. So you are correct!